# Git ignore whitespaces for specific file types

Tags: git, whitespace, merge-conflict-resolution

When merging git branches that produce a conflict I'm ignoring whitespaces by using:

```
-Xignore-all-space
```

But now I need to resolve **ignoring** whitespaces for **some type of files** and **not ignoring** whitespaces for **other types**.

I'm checking on the `gitattributes`file but not sure if this will help with a solution.

Comment: You *can* do this with a merge driver and `.gitattributes`. Unfortunately you'll need to find a merge driver that duplicates the `-Xignore-all-space` work. The one that is provided with Git (`git merge-file`) does not have that option—though it really ought to...